# 'sh run global' and 'sh run nat' yield no output but a ton of NAT in 'sh run'

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, nat

As the topic says, I'm investigating NAT on a clients ASA - it's running old 7.2 train code - I execute '**sh run global**' and '**sh run nat**' - the latter command only returns a single nat 0 line.

When I do a '**sh run | b static**' (which I thought would've shown up under one of the previous two commands!) I get a long list of policy based nat in the format of '**static (outside,inside) x.x.x.x access-list** '  Which is what I would expect to have seen from one of those previously attempted commands.

What commands need to be run to see *everything* involving nat on a 7.2 ASA?  I am not seeing any kind of DST nat (which I expect in this particular case) for the tunnel I'm looking at, but yet the tunnel is up and passing traffic, so it's happening somewhere!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `sh run` and read the whole output. Firewall configurations can be *complex*.

Comment: This is a major enterprise edge VPN FW, it's got a massive config so unfortunately that's not an option.  I was more or less looking for a comprehensive list of sh X commands to pull everything related to nat quickly - if you have any insight for 7.2 that would be great!  Thanks either way for your reply

Comment: Been there... `wr net` is the answer. (ie. look at it offline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`show global`
`show nat`
`show static`
`show conduit` (unless you've switched to ACLs)

Of course, that's going to be 90% of the entire configuration anyway. (more if pdm isn't enabled, thus flooding the config with *pdm location ...*)

Comment: ASA doesn't have pdm, they use asdm. ASA doesn't have conduits either

Comment: v7.2 does, as I recall -- been a long time since I used 7.2 (unsupported, but it will accept the command)

Comment: I know you as someone who values precision and truth, so I'll take your word for it.  I did not find pdm commands myself when I searched CCO, but I don't have an ASA that I'm willing to test with

Comment: Marking this as the answer since it more concisely wraps up how to address the aim of seeing all NAT configuration on a device via sh commands.  I have only seen mention of conduit on PIX, for reference.

Answer (score 3):

'show run static' is a usable show command as well.

Comment: Excellent, between - sh run nat, sh run global, and sh run static I feel like that is every NAT related show command for 7.2.  I'm going to leave this open for a few more days in case anyone else has insight, otherwise, I'll mark your answer as correct.  Thank you!